# phone number search postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

Suppose I have the following data in the "people" table

```
 id     name      phone_number
 1      Pete      +651234-5678
 2      John      1234 56 78 Main number
```

If I had a search string of "123456789" how would I extract the rows that match the phone number - I assume some regex is required but what is the best approach to do this in Postgres?

Comment: Best approach, IMO, have a column with a cleaned-up (canonicalised) number. Maybe even a separate column for area code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this will work

```
 x="SELECT id FROM people WHERE regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g') = '12345678';"
```

or perhaps

```
x="SELECT id FROM people WHERE regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g') LIKE '12345678';"
```

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 2):

Your original search string would not be found of course but I think mine is the complete answer - only votes will tell??

```
select *, regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')  
from people 
where position ( '12345678' in regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')) >= 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE phone_number ~ '^1234\s*56\s*78.*'
```

The pattern `\s*` will match zero or more spaces. The regex will match any of the following:

```
1234 56 78 Main number
123456 78 some text
12345678
```